# Why are relational operators overloaded as non-member function in STL string?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I was going through the documentation for STL strings at - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/.

In it, I found that the relational operators are overloaded as non-member functions. Is there any reason why they are overloaded as non-member functions as opposed to member functions?

Comment: Just to mention that cplusplus.com is very old (it targets C++11).  https://en.cppreference.com is more up to date.

Comment: Note that you should not rely on the relational operators being member functions or non-member functions. All that you should rely on is that the expression `a < b` (and related ones) is valid and does what we expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloading them as non-member functions allows the LHS of the operator to be converted to type `std::string`.  For example, the following does not work should `operator==` be a member:

```
std::string name = "foo";
if ("foo" == name)
    // ...
```

That's because `"foo".operator==(name)` is not a valid expression.